# Idle connections from initialSize remain alive, passed evictiontimeout even when it is never borrowed

Tags: jdbc, connection-pooling

This part of my tomcat's `server.xml`. Three other resources use similar configuration.

```
    <Resource name="APPNXA" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://[masked]"
              username="[masked]" password="[masked]"
              maxActive="100" maxWait="10000"
              maxIdle="100" minIdle="1"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="150000"
              numTestsPerEvictionRun="2"
              testOnBorrow="false"
              testOnReturn="false"
              testWhileIdle="true" />
    <Resource name="APPXA" auth="Container"
              type="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
              factory="com.atomikos.tomcat.EnhancedTomcatAtomikosBeanFactory"
              uniqueResourceName="APPXA"
              maxPoolSize="400"
              minPoolSize="2"
              xaDataSourceClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource"
              xaProperties.databaseName="[masked]"
              xaProperties.serverName="[masked]"
              xaProperties.port="[masked]"
              xaProperties.user="[masked]"
              xaProperties.password="[masked]"
              xaProperties.url="jdbc:mysql://[masked]"
              testQuery="select 1"
              maintenanceInterval="60" />
```

The thing is that this creates 34`(1)` initial connections, which I'm almost certain that is never used again, is not closed while my application is busy, creating and closing new connections.

It's confusing because they are normally closed after `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` when having no other connections.

[image: Connections way past eviction time]

[image: New connections created for transactions]

---

**Question**

1. I monitored these initial 34 connections by every seconds, and there seems to be no query used on them. They are always in `sleep` status. But why are they not closed?
2. Why are they not borrowed by my application service? Why does my application creates new connections ignoring idle connections?

(1) 3 of `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool`, of which initialSize's default is "10", = 30
and 2 of `com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean` of which minPoolSize="2" from  = 4
thus 34 total